# GCP Cloud build ignores timeout settings

Tags: node.js, docker, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I use Cloud Build for copying the configuration file from storage and deploying the app to `App Engine flex`. 
The problem is that the build fails every time when it lasts more than 10 minutes. I've specified timeout in my cloudbuild.yaml but it looks like it's ignored. Also, I configured `app/cloud_build_timeout` and set it to 1000. Could somebody explain to me what is wrong here?

My `cloudbuild.yaml` looks in this way:

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
    args: ["cp", "gs://myproj-dev-247118.appspot.com/.env.cloud", ".env"]
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    args: ["app", "deploy"]
    timeout: 1000s
timeout: 1600s
```

My `app.yaml` use custom env that build it from Dockerfile and looks like this:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: dev
```

Dockerfile also contains nothing special, just installing dependencies and app building:

```
FROM node:10 as front-builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY front-end .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build:web

FROM node:12
WORKDIR /app
COPY api .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
COPY .env .env
EXPOSE 8080
COPY --from=front-builder /app/web-build web-build
CMD npm start
```

Comment: is the first step taking 10 minutes

Comment: @SHASHIKUMARKL no, the first one is fast. Takes around 30 sec.

Comment: are you getting status as Failure or Timeout

Comment: don't use a timeout for steps

Comment: @SHASHIKUMARKL I've added a timeout for step just as one more try. Without it build fails in the same way. I'm getting 
TIMEOUT
ERROR: context deadline exceeded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running `gcloud app deploy` directly for an App Engine Flex app, from your local machine for example, under the hood it spawns a Cloud Build job to build the image that is then deployed to GAE (you can see that build in Cloud Console > Cloud Build). This build has a 10min timeout that can be customized via:

```
gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 1000
```

Now, the issue here is that you're issuing the `gcloud app deploy` command from within Cloud Build itself. Since each individual Cloud Build step is running in its own Docker container, you can't just add a previous step to customize the timeout since the next one will use the default `gcloud` setting.

You've got several options to solve this:

- Add a build step to first build the image with `docker build`, upload it to Google Cloud Registry. You can set a custom timeout on these steps to fit your needs. Finally, deploy your app with `glcoud app deploy --image-url=IMAGE-URL`.
- Create your own [custom gcloud builder](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/cloud-builders#writing_your_own_custom_builder) where `app/cloud_build_timeout` is set to your custom value. You can derive it from the [default gcloud builder Dockerfile](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/blob/master/gcloud/Dockerfile) and add `/builder/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 1000`

Comment: For anyone that stumbles across this, there is now a better solution via the Cloud Build config: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-appengine.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case if you are using Google Cloud Build with Skaffold, remember checking the skaffold.yaml if you setted the `timeout` option inside the `googleCloudBuild` section in `build`. For example:

```
build: 
  googleCloudBuild: 
    timeout: 3600s
```

Skaffold will ignore the gcloud config of the machine where you are running the deploy. For example it will ignore this CLI command: `gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 3600`