# invalid cloud build timeout?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

We have a build that takes anywhere from 1 minute to 15 minutes(monobuild that is not parallized yet so it may build 8 servers or 1).  It was timing out so I modified the build file to

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/continuous-deploy
  timeout: 1200s
```

I also ran these commands(the last one failed though even though I got that from another post so it worked for them somehow)...

```
Deans-MacBook-Pro:orderly dean$ gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 1250
Updated property [app/cloud_build_timeout].
Deans-MacBook-Pro:orderly dean$ gcloud config set builds/timeout 1300
Updated property [builds/timeout].
Deans-MacBook-Pro:orderly dean$ gcloud config set container/build-timeout 1350
ERROR: (gcloud.config.set) Section [container] has no property [build-timeout].
Deans-MacBook-Pro:orderly dean$
```

I get the following error that anything greater than 10 minutes is invalid on google

```
invalid build: invalid timeout in build step #0: build step timeout "20m0s" must be <= build timeout "10m0s"
```

Why MUST it be less than 10m0s?  I really need our builds to be about 20 minutes.

I was going off of

[Why can't I override the timeout on my Google Cloud Build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60070274/why-cant-i-override-the-timeout-on-my-google-cloud-build)

and

[GCP Cloud build ignores timeout settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60431732/gcp-cloud-build-ignores-timeout-settings)

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeout of the steps should be less or equal than the timeout of the whole task.

By setting the timeout at the step level to 20 minutes it is causing the error as the default timeout for the whole task is 10 minutes by default.

The way to avoid this happenning is to set the timeout of the full task to be grater or equal to the the timeout of the specific steps.

I added a small example on how to define this.

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/continuous-deploy
  timeout: 1200s # Step Timeout

timeout: 1200s  # Full Task Timeout
```